# Why does Apache try to serve content from subdirectories when I have a catch-all mod_rewrite rule in place?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a web root with a structure like this:

```
/var/www/html
├── index.php
├── .htaccess
├── private
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── private.jpg
│   ├── stuff.jpg
```

In the `.htaccess` file I have the following simple, catch-all rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Theoretically this should catch every request and forward it to `index.php`, including any requests to the "private" directory.

For example a request to `https://example.com/private` should result in `index.php` being served (with `/private` being in PHP's `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` variable).

However that is not happening. What's actually happening is Apache is ignoring the catch-all rewrite and serving the content of the private directory.

Why is this happening? I was under the impression that a catch-all rewrite rule like that should capture every request including requests for subdirectories. In fact I have seen code recommended to *prevent* subdirectories being caught, like this:

```
# Note I am not using this code
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

**Important:** I don't want a solution on how to make a folder private, specifically. I know how to do that; what I'm trying to figure out is why my catch-all rewrite is being ignored or overridden by the presence of a subdirectory. Why is Apache serving the subdirectory first instead of sending it to `index.php`?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite module enabled?

Comment: @OMiShah Yes it is.

Comment: where you have hosted this files ? on which server? and check if your server allow htaccess override.

Comment: When in doubt … enable rewrite logging, and then check what is actually going on.

Comment: I tried your code, it works as you expect for me.  There must be something else going on, eg your `.htaccess` isn't really being read.